# Jenkins(BlueOcean) failing to build the PR created in BitBucket

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, jenkins-blueocean

After upgrading Jenkins to 2.235.5 and git 2.28.0, I'm seeing build failure on PR that's created in BitBukcet with the below errors

```
Branch indexing
ERROR: Could not do lightweight checkout, falling back to heavyweight
java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL: /rest/api/1.0/**repodetails**/browse/Jenkinsfile?at=pull-requests%2F823%2Fmerge&start=0&limit=500
at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.server.client.BitbucketServerAPIClient.getRequest(BitbucketServerAPIClient.java:834)
at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.server.client.BitbucketServerAPIClient.getFileContent(BitbucketServerAPIClient.java:1129)
at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.filesystem.BitbucketSCMFile.content(BitbucketSCMFile.java:98)
at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFile.contentAsString(SCMFile.java:335)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.SCMBinder.create(SCMBinder.java:107)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:309)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
```

```
 git.exe checkout -f dsadsdsaddsb2610278033e8sajdgasjgda # timeout=10
ERROR: Checkout failed
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git.exe checkout -f dsadsdsaddsb2610278033e8sajdgasjgda" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: reference is not a tree: dsadsdsaddsb2610278033e8sajdgasjgda
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2450)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$1100(CliGitAPIImpl.java:84)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2767)
Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout dsadsdsaddsb2610278033e8sajdgasjgda
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2791)
at jenkins.plugins.git.MergeWithGitSCMExtension.checkout(MergeWithGitSCMExtension.java:144)
at jenkins.plugins.git.MergeWithGitSCMExtension.decorateRevisionToBuild(MergeWithGitSCMExtension.java:110)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.determineRevisionToBuild(GitSCM.java:1063)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1168)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:125)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:155)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.SCMBinder.create(SCMBinder.java:142)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:309)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
```

Is this an issue with Jenkins or BitBucket? Did anyone have the same issue?

Comment: can someone help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to enable an option check for api for bitbucket plugin under configure system
[image]

Comment: Which option? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @VonC Added screenshot